# XSLT Namespace Change

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

I have the following:

```
<Data xmlns:x="Namespace.com">
    <Node></Node>
    <Node2></Node2>
    <Node3></Node3>
</Data>
```

How using XSLT can I change the one namespace within the Data node without seeing the namespace declaration appear everywhere else.

Desired Output:

```
<Data xmlns:x="TheNewNamespace.com">
    <Node></Node>
    <Node2></Node2>
    <Node3></Node3>
</Data>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="TheNewNamespace.com">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Mike, Thanks. But you should notice, that in your sample all elements are in default namespace, not in `Namespace.com`. My solution puts all elements in `TheNewNamespace.com` namespace.

Comment: The sample just reflects the layout of my actual xml document and even though that may be the case XSLT still reads it as if it was in a namespace :/ if I dont declare it when trying to parse I wont find any nodes etc.

Comment: Have since been asked to also add `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` into the namespace so it now includes two, how would I add the second in as cant get it to output as such.